# Invalid MAC Address with correct format

Tags: networking, mac-address

I am making a program that generates random MAC addresses and I am having validation issues.  For instance the following MAC address shows up as invalid:

```
E7:BA:1E:34:9B:B0
```

Each group here is between the 0-255 hex value range though, whats the deal?  Am I missing some other formatting constraint?

Comment: Are you taking into account the flags in the first octet? Also, there is no specific format. There are formats that use dashes, and some that use colons. Also, there are various numbers of digits in each section, depending on the format. You need to determine the format required by whatever you are using.

Comment: When I say format I do not mean the delimeter, maybe I should have been more clear on that.  From what I read the range of a valid MAC address is from 00 00 00 00 00 00 to FF FF FF FF FF FF.  MY example clearly falls in between that range yet still comes up as invalid.

Also what do you mean by flags in the first octet?

Comment: Based on the address you have there, it is a local, group address. The low-order two bits of the first octet of the address are the U/L and I/G flags. You have them set.

Comment: Is there a rule set associated with this I can read about?  I am a network layman so this doesn't really mean much to me without context.

Comment: Just search, and you can find: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Comment: No offense, but I have read through the wiki page.  I wouldn't post here without doing that bare minimum research first.  Are you able to explain what impact these flags have on the validity of the whole address or point me to a resource that might be able to?

Comment: The flags are clearly explained in that article, and there are many other articles that also explain them. You could always go to the source: the IEEE.

Comment: Their definition is there however their impact on validation is not, or at least it is not obvious.  If you have any more insight it would be helpful if not then please don't worry about linking generic top level wiki pages.

Answer (score 1):

That address doesn't have a valid manufacturer id.

Perhaps your "validation" step needs a valid manufacturer id.

For instance 4c:34:88:c7:65:7e  identifies as "Intel Corporate" using the first 3 bytes

Here is a list of manufacturer ids on github

https://gist.github.com/aallan/b4bb86db86079509e6159810ae9bd3e4

Comment: So lets say we take a validation site like: http://sqa.fyicenter.com/1000208_MAC_Address_Validator.html#Result

Do you think it is safe to assume that its checking not just my format, but also that this is actually a registered MAC with a manufacturer?

Comment: I just tried swapping out the first three octets with some random OUIs, still invalid.

Comment: That's like asking what my "validation" step is on an IP address.  There's a certain format it must follow and a range of values each octet can fall under.  There may be some other constraints for MACs as well that I just don't know about because I am not a network engineer hence why I am asking a question here.  My "validation" step is that the MAC address is being rejected by the program I am interfacing with so I am trying to define what is and isn't valid.  I am spot checking with the site I linked in the previous comment.,...

Comment: IP Addresses are a great example.  For example on AWS VPC, 4 addresses in each subnet range are invalid and not allowed - but that is a specific feature of AWS.  If the program you are interfacing with is a black box - there's not much anyone can do.  If the program you are interfacing with has some kind of declared spec then I'm sure someone can help you work with this